# WebP-transform doesn't work with >600 pixel height

Tags: craft3

I am currently playing around with Craft's built-in transform for WebP. I am using GD driver. In general I am able to generate WebP files from my assets. That works well. But it only works up to a specific target height of the transform.

format: webp / height: 500 / quality 100: = works

format: webp / height: 600 / quality 100 = doesn't work

format: webp / height: 600 / quality 10 = works

format: webp / height: 700 / quality 10 = doesn't work

Doesn't works mean, that I just see a white area instead of an image. Works mean, WebP was successfully generated and I can see it in the browser.

Any idea to get this thing running? It would be so awesome to be able to generate webp right out of Craft assets.

Comment: Any errors in the logs? One guess might be PHP is running out of memory?

Comment: @RitterKnight Can't find any errors in the logs. Memory Limit of PHP is 256M at the moment. Is there any other limit which could affect GD rendering?